# Insert an element into specific location in list using cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.1

I want to insert an element into a list in a specific position. I don't want to replace the previous element but rather push everything forward.  Is there a way to do this natively in the cassandra or must I take the list out and rewrite it?
thank you.

**from the datastax documentation:**
Add an element at a particular position using the list index position in square brackets

```
UPDATE users SET top_places[2] = 'riddermark' WHERE user_id = 'frodo';
```

When you add an element at a particular position, Cassandra reads the entire list, and then writes only the updated element. Consequently, adding an element at a particular position results in greater latency than appending or prefixing an element to a list.

Comment: Still does not seem possible. Even though the documentation seems to indicate that it is:
(https://docs.datastax.com/en/archived/ddaccql/doc/cql/cql_using/useInsertList.html). Quote: "To add an element at a particular position, the database reads the entire list, and then rewrites the part of the list that needs to be shifted to the new index positions."

Answer (score 2):

> I don't want to replace the previous element but rather push everything forward

You can't do that, you need to read and rewrite the entire list